# Windows Phone show message in notification area

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How is it possible to show toast from the Windows Phone application which will be displayed in the notification area too. Like for example Email agent on the Windows Phone.

[image: Message from the email agent in the notification area]

The ShellToast works fine, but only when the application is in the background.

Thank you Myth

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation, the Show method of ShellToast will not display the notification when the app is in foreground.

> While the ShellToast.Show method can be called from any application, a toast will not be displayed if the current foreground application is the caller of the ShellToast.Show method. This means that this should primarily be used by a background agent.

However, you can use [Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) toolkit in order to make a ToastPrompt, which act same as your ShellToast.

```
private void DisplayToast()
{
    var toast = CreateToast();
    toast.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

    toast.Show();
}

private static ToastPrompt CreateToast()
{
    return new ToastPrompt
    {
        Title = "MyToast",
        TextOrientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical,
        Message = "Toast message",
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    };
}
```

Just be careful using it because you must send a notification in the main thread (by using a `Dispatcher`).
Hope that helps !
kindrashunt